# Why am I getting "NextRouter was not mounted" here?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to apply [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#shallow-routing) to render components based on an URL query. So I can do this: `page?type=digital`.

I tried this:

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // You might not need to navigate on mount if the URL is expected to be set correctly before loading the page.
    // If you do need to set an initial `type`, consider doing so conditionally or in response to a user action.
  }, []);

  // Optionally, listen for changes in the `type` query parameter
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.type) {
      // Handle changes, e.g., fetch data or update state based on the new `type`
      // This is more relevant if there are additional side effects or data fetching based on the query parameter.
    }
  }, [router.query.type]);

  function renderForm() {
    const { type } = router.query;
    switch (type) {
      case 'digital':
        return <div>Digital Form</div>;
      case 'physical':
        return <div>Physical Form</div>;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  return <div>{renderForm()}</div>;
}

export default Page;
```

But I'm getting this error on this line `const router = useRouter();`:

```
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Nextjs **Page router** then the above code should work.

But, it seems that you are using  Nextjs **App router** which doesn't allow use of **useRouter** from "**next/router**". Instead, try to import **useRouter** from "**next/navigation**"

Comment: If I do that, I get:  `Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.`

Comment: For that you can do like:

import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
 const params: any = useSearchParams();

const x = params.get("type"))